# How to change a non diagonally dominant matrix into a diagonally dominant matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Suppose, I have the system of equations:

[System of Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX3n5.png)

Converting the equation to matrix form, we will get:

[image: Matrix]

My goal is to solve the system using Gauss-Seidel Method. However, the matrix is obviously not diagonally dominant. Is there a way to transform the matrix so that it becomes diagonally dominant?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your *matrix* is not a **matrix**. It's just a triplet of equations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to get the matrix of coefficients
$$A= \begin{pmatrix}1&1&-1\\5&5&2\\3&2&5 \end{pmatrix}$$
into a diagonally dominant form because neither in row 1 nor row 2 there is an element with $|c| \ge |a|+|b|$ where $a,b,c$ are the three numbers in each row.
If you want to know if it is possible to get the matrix into diagonally dominant form in order to check for convergence, here is another method to do that:

To check if the Gauss-Seidel Method is converging here you would have to calculate the spectral radius of the iteration matrix. The iteration matrix for the Gauss-Seidel algorithm is $B= I-(D+L)^{-1}A$ where $L$ is the lower triangle of $A$. If you calculate this you will get
$$B= \begin{pmatrix}0&-1&1\\0& 1 & -7/5\\ 0& 1/5 & -1/25 \end{pmatrix}$$

In order for the Gauss-Seidel method to converge (for arbitrary starting vector $x_0$) we have to check if $\rho(B)$, the spectral radius is $<1$. The eigenvalues of $B$ are
$$\lambda_1 = 0, \quad \lambda_{2,3} = \frac{12 \pm i \sqrt 6}{25}$$
all of which have absolute value $<1$. This means that the Gauss-Seidel method
$$x_k = Bx_{k-1} + (D+L)^{-1}b$$
where $b$ is the original right side will converge - no matter which starting vector $x_0$ you choose.